# How do I display specific lines of text from a website in Java?

Tags: java

I am trying to recreate a C# program I made in Java. I used the the htmlagilitypack and XPaths to display text from a website in the C# program. Is there a library for Java in which I can use XPaths or is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) -- a fairly-recent and decent-looking Java HTML parsing library, which seems quite powerful and easy to use, with nice CSS-like selector syntax for accessing content.